# Static html Code in Java Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am new at programming Web applications and have a question about Java HttpServlet. How do I use long static html code? I have a Webpage with dynamic parts so I can not use html only, but it´s only a small part of the page who is dynamic the Rest is static. In the moment I write the static part of the page like this:

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println("<html>");
writer.println("<head><title>Hello World Servlet</title></head>");
writer.println("<body>");
writer.println("    <h1>Hello World</h1>");
writer.println("<body>");
writer.println("</html>");
```

But I am quit sure that this isn´t an god style. I looked for a better solution for a while but didn´t find a better solution, which is caused by the fact I didn´t for what I have to look. Can someone please post a Link where I read something about this.

At the end I have to apologize for my bad English, but I´m not a native speaker.

Than you very much
Johannes

Comment: Is there any problem to use JSP?

Comment: Johannes be clear in what you want ....

Comment: Where did you search for a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the servlets as controller in your MVC application, and use JSP to handle the view. So, instead printing a lot of HTML code to the response, do a forward to the next view (jsp file). Here's a basic example of a servlet and a JSP file as view.

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("salute", "Hello world from Servlet!");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/realView.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

And in your realView.jsp file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Real View</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${salute}
</body>
</html>
```

So, just access to this URL: `http://yourserverip/yourAppName/hello` in your browser and you will get the a HTML 5 page with content posted from your servlet.

You can find more details about this explanation and another sample in [StackOverflow Servlets wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Answer (score 2):

If [Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) - which is designed to work with JSF, but can work on top of pure Servlets and a whole set of **web frameworks** - is not an option and you don't want to use [JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html) as suggested by @Luiggi, there are several standalone **template engines** (maybe that was the term you were missing) for Java:

- [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)
- [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/)
- [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html)
- [Chunk Template](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/examples/ChunkExample)
- [Rythmn](http://rythmengine.org/)
- [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/)
- [Casper](https://code.google.com/p/casper/)

(Just to mention a few)

Of course that sooner or latter you will may realize that you need more than a template engine + servlets. Once you do, [let me Google that for you](http://bit.ly/1cbZ8lk).